# What is the exact definition of whether resistors are in series or in parallel?

Tags: resistors, parallel, series

Is there generally any easy way how to say whether resistors are in series or parallel? Sometimes, I have trouble understanding whether resistors are in series or parallel and then I start doing mistakes based on that.  It is definitely not same as already existing question because I am asking in general whether there is way to know parallel/series resistor by looking at circuit.

Comment: To have a good answer, it might be good if you would include a description what is hard in understanding when resistors are in series or parallel. Maybe an example?

Comment: @Elliot Alderson. The linked question is about a specific circuit. This question is general about any circuit. Surprisingly, I haven't found another question that specifically ask how to tell series and parallel apart in all cases. All I can find is questions that ask about a particular circuit.

Comment: @Justme I indeed meant resistors in general, if there is any easy way to say so. Because in link provided circuit is not hard to understand whatsoever, but there tend to be harder circuits so I have been wondering if there is a way.

Comment: @Filip the same rules apply, no matter how hard or easy circuit. Perhaps give an example of a hard circuit?

Comment: @Justme So what are those so called "rules"  that apply for any circuit no matter how hard it is when it comes to parallel/series resistors?

Comment: @Filip How do you currently decide if resistors are in series, parallel, or neither? Let's build on that then.

Comment: @Elliot Alderson. I disagree on the removal because this question is not a duplicate of the one linked: this question is about a general rule, the question linked is about a specific circuit.

Comment: @JYelton. I disagree on the removal because this question is not a duplicate of the one linked: this question is about a general rule, the question linked is about a specific circuit.

Comment: @Andy aka. I disagree on the removal because this question is not a duplicate of the one linked: this question is about a general rule, the question linked is about a specific circuit.

Comment: @DavideAndrea This isn't a "removal" - it's a closure with a link to a duplicate (or near-duplicate, in this case). Both questions are about determining whether resistors are in series or parallel, this one more general while the linked is more specific. While I agree it may not be a precise duplicate, I think OP will gain enough insight from the linked question that it will be useful.

Comment: @JYelton now nobody can ask similar question to one previously asked because of its similarity? Linked one did not answer my question but here it has been explained excellently in my opinion, so am I just supposed to magically gain insight from linked question?

Comment: @Filip Similar questions are able to be closed as duplicates by community votes. I voted that this was similar enough to qualify. One of the site goals is to link these questions together (see "Linked" section at right) so users can check similar and related questions easily. Feel free to disagree and vote to reopen if desired. You can also vote on and accept Davide's answer.

Comment: @Filip I will add that [ThePhoton's answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/524436/2028) to the linked question should answer your question. Excerpt: _"If two components are end-to-end so that all the current flowing out of one must flow into the other, then they are in series. If two components are connected at both ends, so that the exact same voltage must appear across both components then they are in parallel."_ This is the reason I felt it was a duplicate.

Comment: @JYelton but still, here the explanation was more clear to me. So I do not see why I need to only take insights from one previously asked. Whatever, thanks for your concern regarding my "almost" duplicate question.

Comment: You can ask related questions if you didn't understand the answers you found, but at an minimum you need to explain what it is you didn't understand in the previous question and answers. Otherwise you are asking everyone to guess what it is you didn't understand.

Comment: @user1850479 seems someone understood exactly what I meant, so I do not understand relevance of your comment but thanks for contribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that your question only makes sense if there are additional components besides the two resistors. Note also that "in series" and "in parallel" are but two of a great variety of possible circuits. They are not the only two choices.

With that said, then, to see which, ask yourself these questions:

1. "Does the entire current that flows through resistor A also flow through resistor B?". If the answer is "yes, then they are in series.
2. "Does the entire voltage that appears across resistor A also appear across resistor B?". If the answer is "yes, then they are in parallel.

- If the answer is "no" to both the above, then they are neither in series nor in parallel.
- If the answer is "yes" to both the above, then they are neither in series nor in parallel (they are the only two components in a circuit and both the voltage and the current are 0).

Comment: Thank you, may I ask is that the only thing to follow with which I can solve uncertainty of series/parallel circuits? I have also tried to look for answer somewhere on the net but the only thing that I have found was that when two resistors share two same nodes ( while they are directly connected to them), then it is parallel and when there is only one node, it is series. Do you have any knowledge of whether or not it works like that too? Or should I go only by what you have suggested is right way to approach the    circuit?

Comment: " is that the only thing to follow with which I can solve uncertainty of series/parallel circuits?" Yes. "when two resistors share two same nodes ..." that's also true. Either method will give the same results. But, again, be aware that series and parallel are not the only options.

Comment: Thank you I think I understand it now thanks to you.